# Multiple line chart issue from json

Tags: d3.js

Following is my [code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b97_tb0YecoYooq5wsp3m60NsHR4a5-Z). I have been trying to plot humidity and dew point in basis of months in the axis. But I am getting an error of data undefined and also the month in the axis comes in number.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
    <title> Data Visualization - Binding Dataset to Shapes Using D3 </title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.legend {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-anchor: middle;
}

</style>
<body>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var priceline = d3.svg.line()   
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.dew); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.json("weatherdata.json", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.history.date.mon);
        d.dew = +d.history.dailysummary[0].meandewptm;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.dew; }));

    // Nest the entries by symbol
    var dataNest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {return d.dew;})
        .entries(data);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();   // set the colour scale

    legendSpace = width/dataNest.length; // spacing for legend

    // Loop through each symbol / key
    dataNest.forEach(function(d,i) { 

        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .style("stroke", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
                return d.color = color(d.key); })
            .attr("d", priceline(d.values));

        // Add the Legend
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("x", (legendSpace/2)+i*legendSpace) // spacing
            .attr("y", height + (margin.bottom/2)+ 5)
            .attr("class", "legend")    // style the legend
            .style("fill", function() { // dynamic colours
                return d.color = color(d.key); })
            .text(d.key);

    });

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am not sure how will i solve it. Can anyone please help. I am sharing the [data file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10GT_ediM7CcH7UHCiU8_ySWKKCtE7pAv) with the [current issue](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ahhzP9JrzK4wQAzEgcj3uEKGtwOG4N4W) I am facing.

I have attached the [model data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tNgKeDHtuYNNpwbY9GsMEAQ-2n14KXCO) the way it should look like:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code here and do not only link it.

Comment: I am trying to.but it does not appear the way it is suppose to be. That is why I have linked it

Comment: [Have a look here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88541/how-to-write-code-in-a-question-or-answer) to see how to write code. Take your time and edit your question accordingly, because nobody here will click those google drive links (I mean I won't).

Comment: Thanks.. I will try to modify

Comment: I have another question .. input for time format is "December 31, 1980".. what should i use to plot it as month (such as Jan or Feb etc) in X axis in D3 ver 3.

Answer (score 0):

For your question on Date format for the X axis , sorry i put an answer because i can't comment (need more reputation).

I think you need to do something like this

```
chart.xAxis
.tickFormat(function(d) {
return d3.time.format('%b')(format(d)); 
});
```

That will display only the month.